# AWS SNS cross region vs same region cost and time difference

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-billing, aws-regions

Is there any difference in costing if I send sms using aws sns to australia numbers but while setting region of aws-sdk I use ap-northeast-1 instead of ap-southeast-2?

Comment: Well, that's easy: https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from reading the documentation: no.

Looking at the [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/) and entering *Australia* as the region prices vary by carrier.

There is no way to select a region for SNS so from that I conclude that the pricing is the same regardless in which region you use SNS.